# Best approach for applying specific client-side logic to a set of related elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML/CSS menu that I need to integrate with a legacy ASP application. Depending on the user or the environment, certain menu items are shown or hidden based on a variety of client-side conditions.

Most of the time the client-side conditions determine whether to show or hide a single menu item, but there are occasions where a group of items may require the same condition on the client-side. I apologize in advance if this is confusing, but here is an example:

```
<li>Link 1</li> 
<li>Link 2</li>
<li>Link 3</li>
<li>Link 4</li>
```

In the above example, links 1, 2, and 4 should only be displayed if variable `bFoo == 60`. Link 3 should be displayed regardless.

I'm wondering what the best approach is for applying specific logic to a group of elements that may or may not be sequential. Obviously, I could assign a separate ID to each element, and group them in my selector like this:

```
$("#link1, #link2, #link4").toggle(bFoo == 60);
```

I could also give the elements a common class like so:

```
$(".special-links").toggle(bFoo == 60);
```

I'm leaning towards the first option for the sake of clarity, but I'm wondering if there's a better option available that I haven't considered yet. There are different variations of the above example throughout the whole menu which contains 100+ links, so I want my solution to be as maintainable as possible. Is what I've mentioned above the best I can hope for, or am I being really stupid right now and overlooking an obvious and easy solution?

I hope what I'm asking for makes sense. If my question is unclear, please let me know and I will try to explain it better.

Comment: is your variable going to be made of numbers ? . if variable is preceded by a letter, it can be then applied in HTML/CSS as a class. so you could have links with class=" a60 a75 a3" and set display: to any class you wish

Comment: No, unfortunately not preceded by numbers, otherwise that would probably be a good solution. Might still be even though they're not prefixed by a character. Being that they're constants, I could always add a character prefix to the class for readability. That would kind of break the semantic flow of the stylesheet though...

Comment: Id selector is the fastest you may take that into consideration

Comment: you could attach variable to bunch of letters. here is what i was thinking of http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk (this is just via CSS for a galley with 100 images) show 0 10 of a kind or 100. Class are easely reusable

Comment: @raam86 it look like class are faster : http://jsperf.com/multiple-id-s-vs-class Your statement is true when it's for selecting 1 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id doesn't matter - take whichever approach fits better in your code.

I'd avoid `eval`, though. Use something like this:

```
if (bFoo == 60) {
    $("#link1, #link2, #link4").toggle();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `toggle(bFoo == 60);`?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Yep - you could do that too.

Answer (score 1):

I make my comment an answer (to get comments here ;) )

```
if (bFoo) {
    $(".a"+bFoo).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's similar to my second approach outlined above. The issue I have with this solution is that it will break the semantic naming conventions I'm currently using. I guess if I don't actually add the classes to the stylesheet it doesn't matter that much though... still on the fence with this approach.